# checking validity of decimal input in UITextfield

Tags: swift, uitextfield

One of the UITextfield input should accept decimals. But I want to restrict the user to type only one ".", otherwise the floating point conversion gets messed up if it has more than one "." in the number. How to ensure user does not key in more than one "." as a part of decimal input?

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if ( textField == areaTextField) {
            guard CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)) else {
                return false
            }
        } 
        return true
        
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your approach is wrong to start with; you are way overthinking this. The computer already knows whether a string is a valid number, so just ask it. Don't examine any characters. Don't examine any keys. Simply perform the replacement described by the parameters and ask the computer if the result would be a number:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let rep = (textField.text! as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
    return rep.count == 0 || Double(rep) != nil
}
```

Comment: Tried something like this and did not work for float with decimals
func isNumber(str : String) -> Bool {
  let numberCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.inverted
  let val = !str.isEmpty && str.rangeOfCharacter(from:numberCharacters) == nil
   return val }
when I test individually str.rangeOfCharacter(from:numberCharacters) where str is a decimal gives error: value of type 'Double' has no member 'rangeOfCharacter'
Like I said I want to pass if your keys in integer or decimal, but  if user accidentally keys in more than one decimal then catch it so I can alert user

Comment: Well you're still not doing what I said. You are way overthinking this... To find out if the overall string is a legal decimal number just try to coerce it to Double.